# Не могу сделать :before на задний фон

Tags: html, css

```css
.category-header {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.category-header::after {
    display: none;
}

.category-header h1 {
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;
}

.overlay {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #202225;
    opacity: 0.50;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-header overlay" style="background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/hw7E6x/Blizzard_World.jpg)">
  <h1>Все новости из мира overwatch</h1>
</div>
```

Не получается выставить тег h1 чтобы он был поверх :before, z-index не помогает

Answer (score 1):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.category-header {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.overlay {
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/hw7E6x/Blizzard_World.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(32, 34, 37);
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-header overlay">
  <h1>Все новости из мира overwatch</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1 {

z-index: 999;
position: relative;
}

    .category-header {
        height: 200px;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
    }

    .category-header::after {
        display: none;
    }

    .category-header h1 {
        color: #fff;
        z-index: 100;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .overlay {
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .overlay:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #202225;
        opacity: 0.50;
    }
```

```html
<div class="category-header overlay" style="background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/hw7E6x/Blizzard_World.jpg)">
      <h1>Все новости из мира overwatch</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: В вопросе речь идёт о заголовке, принадлежащем конкретному блоку. Зачем обобщать?

Answer (score 0):

Почему не помогает?

```css
.category-header {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.category-header::after {
    display: none;
}
.category-header h1 {
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;
}
.overlay {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -2;
}
.overlay:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #202225;
    opacity: 0.50;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-header overlay" style="background-image:      url(https://image.ibb.co/hw7E6x/Blizzard_World.jpg)">
     <h1>
        Все новости из мира overwatch
     </h1>
</div>
```